# Third "excellent" on Area 51 - congratulations to all - nearly ready for graduation

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

[Over on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16617/academia), this site has just achieved its third "Excellent" category, having just passed 150 users with a score of at least 200.

We just need to get questions per day up above 5 (currently 3.8, fortnightly median value), keep the number of answers up, and keep visits per day on a rising trend, and we should be ready to graduate out of beta.

(will self-delete as too localised, shortly)

Comment: No, keep this up... it's nice to point out when things are going well, and it'll look nice in the "community bulletin" box on the side :) Thanks to everyone who contributes to the site!

Comment: It's fun. Apparently I kickstarted something useful :)