# No more "needs work" categories

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Along the lines of "[Third excellent..."](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178/third-excellent-on-area-51-congratulations-to-all-nearly-ready-for-graduat), we now have [no more "needs work" categories](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16617/academia), having just bumped over the 5 questions/day mark. This is more of an announcement than a question, so it can be removed later if necessary.

Comment: we dropped below 5 again ... I think it is going to take another week or so (hope I am not being too optimistic) before our questions per day says as okay.

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I will note that with over 1000 questions, there are only 11 "unanswered" questions, which is really very good.

Comment: Is it some software error? 1050 q/260 days in beta only makes 4 q/day...

Comment: @Shyam - I think the value is a rolling mean, but I'm not sure for what period. For visitors per day, it's the rolling 2-week median.

Answer (score 2):

Congrats to all on reaching this nice milestone! (and there's no need to be modest: a lot of SE sites in beta have a hard time maintaining a steady stream of questions after the initial excitement)

Being a newcomer, if I may take this opportunity to give my main impression for my first month here: by increasing our userbase more we will be able to cover more fields of research… and this diversity will bring even more value to the site. Academia is a broad church!

---

A related reminder (yes, I saw someone say “more like nagging”): we have proposed an ad to run on our sibling Stack Exchange sites, but **they need our votes to run**. If you have an account on the following SE sites, please go up vote the ad:

- [TeX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2840/3734): only 1 last vote needed
- [English L&U](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3235/3479): 2 more votes needed
- [Mathematics](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6441/3406): 3 more votes needed
- [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1571/91): 4 votes needed

PS: the [ad itself](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238/community-promotion-ad-to-run-on-other-ses) is a graphics I created with Daniel’s advice… but I am in no way emotionally attached to it, so please consider improving on it or proposing a better design [in the relevant meta discussion](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238/community-promotion-ad-to-run-on-other-ses).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting, good job to everyone who's participated and made this site as good as it is.